# Bonita business data objects

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

I have a simply bonita diagrams with few business objects.  I need to send data from this table to remote service. 
How can I get lost of my tables by groovy script ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a remote service from Bonita process execution you need to use connectors. Bonita provides a wide ranges of connectors. You need to find the one that match your remote service. Note that connector such as REST or web service let you connect to a lot of different system as long as they provide APIs accessible using REST or web services.

You can configure connectors inputs using your process business variables.